# jquery background image change fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some kind of jquery slider. It's almost standard NivoSlider, but i want to change basic images with my own controls.

So I have something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
   <img src="img/slider/start1.jpg"  alt="" />
   <img src="img/slider/start2.jpg"  alt=""/>
   <img src="img/slider/start3.jpg"  alt="" />
</div>

<!--controls-->

<ul class="lista">
   <li class="first"></li><!--thumbnail here on background image-->
   <li class="second"></li>
   <li class="third"></li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

When you click on e.g. second li element, you change main image in slider and thumbnail. The first part works excellent, the second part looks like this (I am a beginner in javascript):

```
    $('.first').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(img/slider/1min_a.jpg)');
    $('.second').css('background', 'url(img/slider/2min.jpg)');
    $('.third').css('background', 'url(img/slider/3min.jpg)');
    }); 

   $('.second').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(img/slider/2min_a.jpg)');    
    $('.first').css('background', 'url(img/slider/1min.jpg)');
    $('.third').css('background', 'url(img/slider/3min.jpg)');
    });     

   $('.third').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'url(img/slider/3min_a.jpg)');
    $('.first').css('background', 'url(img/slider/1min.jpg)');
    $('.second').css('background', 'url(img/slider/2min.jpg)');
    });
```

And I have two questions:
1. How can I make it as simple as possible?
2. How can I add fadeOut / fadeIn effect to prevent image "blink" on background change?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple.

Step 1.learn [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

step 2.Dont code the way you are doing.You shoud make a dynamic slideshow.

In your HTML : `<div class="thumbnail" data-bigimg="image src of your main image" >`

Make sure you load all your Main image source while looping i.e by assigning data-bigimg attribute equal to full path of main image src to each thumb div.

```
$(document).on('click', '.thumbnail', function () {
    var img_src = $(this).attr('data-bigimg');
    $("#main_img").fadeOut(300,function(){
      $("#main_img").attr("src", img_src).fadeIn(500);//main_img is your main Slide show image.
     });
});
```

Explanation :

1. on click of thumb you get the data attribute value .
2. now you assign this img src to the main slideshow image

Change your html:

```
<div class="nivoSlider">
   <img id="main_img" src="img/slider/start1.jpg"  alt="" />
</div>

<!--controls-->

<ul class="lista">
   <li class="thumbnail" data-bigimg="src of main image to be displayed"></li><!--thumbnail here on background image-->
   <li class="thumbnail" data-bigimg="src of main image to be displayed"></li>
   <li class="thumbnail" data-bigimg="src of main image to be displayed"></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: ok, got it, but first: this solution works without any nivoslider js files, so i don't need it any more. But in Nivo you have smooth transitions between images (like opacity or sth) and how can I apply this to my code? And 2nd: I want to change background image of my thumbnail when it's active. How can I do this?

Comment: well you dont need any js if you know how to write your own javascript...all transitions are possible...in this case..the slide wont be possible..but the image can switch with fade in an out...and grab a good book about javascript..